# Android parse.com push notification no action

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I have a problem. parse push notification no action. when i delete installation, and after run again, i have 3 installation, but no send push notification success(pushes sent 0). Can you help me.[image]
[image]

it code :

```
   ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation()
                         .saveInBackground();
        ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
        ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

        // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this
        // line.
        defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

        ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL,
                               true);



  <!-- parse push notification-->
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService"/>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
                <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>

                <!--
                  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name.
                -->
                <category android:name="com.demo"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: what condition you provided while sending push notification